# How to capture screen shot of 1000 web pages concurrently in c#

Tags: webbrowser-control

I need to get screenshot of 1000 URLs using Parallel.Foreach in windows service. I tried to use WebBrowser control but it throws error since it runs only in STA. Kindly tell me how to achieve this task using Parallel.Foreach...

Edit : I am using a third party trial version DLL in below code to process it...

```
Parallel.ForEach(webpages, webPage=>
        {
               GetScreenShot(webPage);
}

public void GetScreenShot(string webPage)
{
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot _Obj;
_Obj = new WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot();
WebsitesScreenshot.WebsitesScreenshot.Result _Result;            
_Result = _Obj.CaptureWebpage(webPage);
if (_Result == WebsitesScreenshot.
            WebsitesScreenshot.Result.Captured)
{
    _Obj.ImageFormat = WebsitesScreenshot.
        WebsitesScreenshot.ImageFormats.PNG;
    _Obj.SaveImage(somePath);
} 
_Obj.Dispose();
}
```

Most of the time this code runs fine upto processing of 80 urls but after that some tasks are being blocked. I don't know why...

Some times error is ContextSwitchDeadlock....as given below...

ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected

Message: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x44d3a8 to COM context 0x44d5d0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that a CLR thread is not sending any messages for an extended period of time. If a process is resource starved causing extended waits during processing this error can occur.

Given that you are trying to process 1000 web pages simultaneously, it would be no surprise that at least some of the threads will become resource starved. Personally, it is surprising to me that you can hit 80 websites without seeing errors.

Back off the number of websites you are trying to processing in parallel and your problems will likely disappear. Since you are running the trial version, there is little else you can do. If you licensed the commercial version you might be able to get support from the vendor. But at a guess, they would simply tell you to do the same thing.

The Websites.Screenshot library can be quite resource intensive depending upon the web page, esp. if the pages have flash. Think of it as being logically equivalent to opening 80 tabs simultaneously in a web browser.

You don't mention whether you are using the 32-bit or the 64-bit version. But the 64-bit version is likely to have fewer resource constraint, esp. memory. IMHO The .Net framework does a poor job of minimizing memory usage, so memory problems can crop up earlier than you would think.

ADDED

Please try limiting the number of threads threads first, e.g.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    Webpages,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, // 10 thread limit
    webPage => { GetScreenShot(webPage); }
);
```

Without access to the source code, you may not be able to change the threading model at all. You might also try setting the timeout to a higher value.

I don't have this control personally and am not willing to install it on my machine to answer a question re: changing the threading model. Unless it is a documented feature, you probably won't be able to do it without changing or at least inspecting the source.

Comment: I wonder is there any other way using WebBrowser control in Parallel.ForEach loop since it throws error stating it should run in STA...

Comment: Ok..I got the point...I have another question here...How can I skip any request inside the loop which is taking too much time or some some sort of wait algorithms inside the loop.

Comment: I think the wait is configurable on the .net library you are using. Inspect the properties of _Obj.

Comment: I have checked it already and found nothing like this...I am not sure how to do it but I think it should be via the particular task which is taking the too much time...

Comment: Check again, they specify that that is one of the options.